# C programming, clearing a string

Tags: c, string, file

So I have some code that gets a user input and compares it in a loop, it will check the first line, then the second, then the third and so on, however the program doesn't get another clean string variable for the next cycle of the loop, as shown here:

```
char text[100], blank[100];
int c = 0, d = 0;

void space(void); 

int main()
{
    int loop=0;
    char str[512];
    char string[512];
    int line=1;
    int dis=1;
    int score=0;
    char text[64];

    FILE *fd;
    fd = fopen("Student Usernames.txt", "r"); //Should be test
    if (fd == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
do
{
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    gets(text);
    while (text[c] != '\0')
   {
      if (!(text[c] == ' ' && text[c] == ' ')) {
       string[d] = text[c];
        d++;
      }
      c++;
   }
   blank[d] = '\0';
   printf("Text after removing blanks\n%s\n", string);

   getch();

    for(loop = 0;loop<line;++loop)
    {
        fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd);
    }
    printf("\nLine %d: %s\n", dis, str);
    dis=dis+1;
     str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
    if(strcmp(string,str) == 0 )
     {
     printf("Match\n");
     score=score+2;
      }
         else
         {
         printf("Nope\n");
         score=score+1;
         }
     getch();
}
while(!feof(fd));
printf("Score: %d",score);
getch();
}
```

For example: Input: Apple (1st word) , 1st line = Apple, Match, Input: Banana, **2nd line = Applea**

Clearly the program has added onto to first input, I want to know how to change this

Edit: Upon reseting c and d back to 0 after each loop the output is now **"AppleBanana"**

Comment: Your code is rather messy, so I didn't read it all -- but are you appending a '\0' to the end of your string?

Comment: `blank[d] = '\0';` --> `string[d] = '\0';` and `c`,`d` need clear each loop.

Comment: `blank[d]= '\0';` should be `string[d]= '\0';`. You need to null terminate your c string. What is the purpose of `blank`?

Comment: Changed it, it didn't work

Comment: Wait, no, I added the c and d reset, it works just fine now, thanks